# tikz gives null character in \document

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

Please why does

```
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \x [remember=\x as \lastx (initially A)] in {B,...,H}{%
  $\overrightarrow{\lastx\x}$,
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

give

```
Missing character: There is no , in font nullfont!
```

in the log file while in document body? Removing the comma (,) after `$` relieves the warning.

Comment: It works for me. You probably need to update some packages. Please add `\listfiles` _before_ `\begin{document}`, and post the file versions here. Alternatively, update your packages (and I hope you are not on a 2009 release).

Comment: @PeterGrill There are no errors or warnings, the commas are missing in the output and the `.log` file shows the lines about `Missing character` quoted in the question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `tikzpicture` environment is not intended to put bare text there. It resets the font to `\nullfont`. The text needs to be placed, for example, as node text.

If you just want to have the `\foreach` loop, then you do not need the `tikzpicture`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\foreach \x [remember=\x as \lastx (initially A)] in {B,...,H}{%
  $\overrightarrow{\lastx\x}$\if\x H\else, \fi
}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: If you just want the `\foreach` loop with no `tikzpictures` in your document, you can use `\usepackage{pgffor}` instead of `\usepackage{tikz}`.

Comment: OK, thanks. I first observed the warning when using `\newforeach` in `\tikzpicture` environment. I thought it was due to a bug in `\newforeach` until I got it replicated by `\foreach`.